Smooth functions with vanished derivatives at the boundary
I need to find a function $f$ in $[a,b]$ which satisfy that
$$
f(a) = f_1, \\
f(b) = f_2, \\
f^{(j)}(a) = 0, \quad j = 1,...,k, \\
f^{(j)}(b) = 0, \quad j = 1,...,k, 
$$
where $f^{(j)}$ is the j-th derivative of $f$. I know we can get a polynomial which depends on k, but it's troublesome. I want to know if there is a special function that can easily solve this problem.

There exists a smooth function $g$ on $\Bbb{R}$ which is 0 for $x\leq 0$ and 1 for $x \geq 1$ (it's described on the Wikipedia page for bump functions; you just need to scroll down a bit). By scaling it appropriately, you can make it fit in the interval $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$, and equal $f_1, f_2$ at the endpoints. Then just extend it as a constant to $[a,b]$. All partial derivatives will equal zero at the endpoints.
